# Add a trailing # to each string of a list results in #//

Tags: c#, string, string-concatenation

I would like to add a trailing # to every string of a list of strings.
The # is added, but as well two `\`. What can I do to correct this piece of code?

Input:

```
Houseplant
```

Algorithm:

```
tmpList = tmpList.Select(hashtag => Path.Combine("#", hashtag)).ToList();
```

Output:

```
#\\Houseplant
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation of `Path.Combine`? (As the name suggests) it doesn’t perform string concatenation.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Surely it's just `tmpList.Select(hashtag => $"{hashtag}#").ToList();` (or `tmpList.Select(hashtag => $"#{hashtag}").ToList();` depending on whether you actually mean "leading" rather than "trailing")

Comment: How are you adding these strings to `tmpList`, surely *before* adding them you could add the `#`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mean to concatenate these as paths (with a `/` separating them) then dont use `Path.Combine`.

You could just use `String.Concat`:

```
tmpList = tmpList.Select(hashtag => String.Concat("#", hashtag)).ToList();
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kjkxgu

Comment: Title of question is "Add a ***trailing*** #.."

Comment: @spender _code of the question_ makes it a prefix. and the naming "hashtag" implies the word trailing was probably a misunderstanding of english. #betimright

Comment: Aaarrrgh ;-) Thanks a lot, now if I look more precise at the code.... Well, typical copy & paste error